# Как добавить новое поле в модель User при использовании django-allauth

Tags: python, django

Хочу добавить новое поле subscriber в модель User (таблица auth_user). В проекте используется django-allauth версии 0.24.1. Джанга 1.9.1

Структура проекта:

```
project
├── config
|   ├── settings
|   |   └── base.py
|   ├── urls.py
|   └── wsgi.py
├── core
|   ├── models.py
|   ├── urls.py
|   └── views.py
├── members
|   ├── migrations
|   ├── static
|   ├── templates
|   ├── forms.py
|   ├── models.py
|   ├── urls.py
|   └── views.py
└── templates
    ├── pages
    |   └── register.html
    └── base.html
```

В config/base.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'members.MyUser'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
```

В members/model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models


class MyUserManager(UserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        user = self.model(email=email, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.')
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.')
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    # extend the base model here
    is_subscriber = models.BooleanField(_('subscriber'), default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        abstract = False

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name
```

В members/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm


class MySignupForm(SignupForm):
    # additional fields
    subscribe = forms.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'subscribe',
        )

    def save(self, user):
        # user.is_subscriber = self.cleaned_data['subscribe']
        user.is_subscriber = 1  # PERMANENT SET TO 1 JUST FOR TEST
        user.save()
        return user
```

В members/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from members.forms import MySignupForm


class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/index.html'


class Register(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/register.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(Register, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('core:home')

        context.update({
            'signup_form': MySignupForm(),
        })
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

И в pages/register.html

```
<form id="signup_form" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ signup_form.email }}
    {{ signup_form.password1 }}
    {{ signup_form.password2 }}
    {{ signup_form.subscribe }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">REGISTER</button>
</form>
```

Все поля, включая необходимый мне subscribe отображаются на сайте нормально. При сабмите все данные пишутся в базу, за исключением subscribe ...
Отладчик в def save(self, user) формы даже не заходит. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил проблему заходом с другой стороны.
Добавил вызов

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'members.forms.SignupForm'
```

и переделал SignupForm не от `allauth.account.forms.SignupForm`, а через `forms.Forms`

members/forms.py

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255, label="Email")
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label="Password again")
    subscribe = forms.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = [
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'subscribe',
        ]

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.is_subscriber = True  # <-- JUST FOR TEST
        user.save()
```